# Rendering Photoshop anim. with transparent background results in "missing codec" (invalid file)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, animation, error

I'm trying to export a Photoshop animation and can get the file with a black background but cannot export it without a background without the getting this [image]

Any help? (I did the proper exporting procedure: [image]

Comment: Some formats are not meant for end user consumption. Quicktime may not be very common anymore as a generic display format. Also note that most players will show black background even in the case that the video has transparency unless its composed on something.

Comment: Not something I know a lot about, but only some file formats support video transparency - see https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/make-white-background-in-mp4-movie-transparent and https://www.digitalrebellion.com/blog/posts/list_of_video_formats_supporting_alpha_channels

Comment: Also not my areas, but I believe QT requires a *mask* to create transparency, it's not something it does inherently.